# Search Bar with Maps app behavior (navigation bar full width when selected)

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm trying to display a search bar that would have exactly the same behavior as the one in native Maps app. I mean:

- search bar in the title view of my navigation bar
- when selected, the search bar occupies the full width of my navigation bar and I display the SearchDisplayController

So far, I managed to get the following behavior:

[image]

As you can see above, I can't manage to get the search bar to occupy the full width on selection. Though, full width + cancel button seems like the default behavior for search bar that are hooked with SearchDisplayController, at least if the search bar was not added to the navigation bar!

Am I missing an obvious way of doing that? Or do I have to customize the navigation bar by myself when `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` is called?

Comment: you can set the displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar, that will occupy the complete navigation bar.

Comment: No, it is already set to `YES`. Apparently that's not sufficient if the search bar is in the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

As long as I do not have the perfect solution, I'm doing the following. But I'm still open to something better!!

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(onCancel)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^(){
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    }];
return YES;
}

- (void)onCancel {
    [self.searchController setActive:NO];
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^(){
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"OpenMenuButton.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(openSideMenu:)];
    }];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =self.doneButton;
    return YES;
}
```

Besides, I'm wondering if Maps app actually use a navigation controller because there are custom behaviors (width of the titleView, animation of the leftBarButton out of the screen) that surprise me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like `UISearchDisplayController` + `UISearchBar` ?
http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/fixing-uisearchdisplaycontroller-on-ios-7/

Comment: Thanks. I am actually already using a UISearchDisplayController but it seems like its default behavior (expansion of the search bar + cancel button apparition) is not "activated" when its corresponding search bar is in a navigation bar titleView. I managed to fix the frame of the display controller if I do not put the search bar in a navigation bar.